# Will Swift evetually have native selectors?

Tags: swift, selector

I understand that in order to use `Selector`s in Swift, one must mark the Swift function `@objc` and have at least `internal` visibility because the function must be exposed to the Objective-C runtime.

So from my understanding, when running those `@objc` marked Swift functions as selectors, Objective-C's core is majorly involved. So I'm wondering will Apple eventually make Swift completely independent from Objective-C as Swift is primarily written in C++?

Comment: No, they wont do it. Swift is completely independent. Its Cocoa and CocoaTouch that is based on selectors. Selectors are not a good thing, they are not type-safe. The way forward is SwiftUI which does not need selectors. Also, you are wrong about the visibility. You can use even private methods as selectors. Thats one of the problems with selectors actually.

Comment: "Objective-C's core is majorly involved" of course, because that's pretty much 99% of what its purpose is. It's just a runtime component that implements the machinery necessary for message passing (selectors are the messages). What exactly is your complaint about that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats a complicated question, and only Apple truly knows. I would say no because of how many apps still use Objective C and the fact the some people still use it in new apps. It would be hard for apple to just completely ignore those developers and potentially take massive amounts of revenue away from themselves  and other developers, on top of most of their OS still uses some Objective C. I hope that makes sense and sorry if people get upset that you asked this on SO.